# How to update Gazebo-2.2 to Gazebo-7?

Tags: gazebo-2.2, ros-indigo, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,
i have installed ROS Indigo on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS-64 bit machine. It includes Gazebo-2.2 with it. I want to update the Gazebo-7.

I want to know -

1. How can i update it to Gazebo-7?
2. If i do update, will there be any issue with my current ROS installation or functionality?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12843/how-to-update-gazebo-2.2-to-gazebo-7?/) by [baila](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2418/baila/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, you can install gazebo-7 with Indigo.

Here is more information:
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baila](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2418/baila/) on 2016-03-14**:
I have used "sudo apt-get install gazebo7". But it is giving me errors like:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gazebo7 : Depends: libgazebo7 (= 7.0.0-1~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gazebo7-common (= 7.0.0-1~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: gazebo7-plugin-base
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

But "apt-mark showhold" is not showing anything.

**Comment by [baila](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2418/baila/) on 2016-03-14**:
Thanks for your help nkoenig. I have updated my gazebo-2.2 by "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo7-ros-pkgs". Hope it will work fine. Thanks.